# Deserializing JSON when inner property names vary

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have JSON which looks something like this (external JSON beyond my control):

```
[
  {
    "currencies": {
      "KGS": {
        "name": "Kyrgyzstani som",
        "symbol": "с"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "currencies": {
      "SOS": {
        "name": "Somali shilling",
        "symbol": "Sh"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And I have a set of classes which I would like this JSON deserialized into

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public OuterClass Currencies { get; set; }
}

public class OuterClass
{
    //Inner property below needs to map to these changing prop names: "KGS", "SOS"
    public InnerClass Inner { get; set; }
}    

public class InnerClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

And Lastly, when I try to deserialize:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<ParentClass>>(responseBody.Content);
```

It's not deserializing properly, because the it cannot map varying Property names to "Inner". Is there a way to handle this scenario?

Comment: It might be easiest to deserialize to a `IDictionary<string, InnerClass>` and omit OuterClass. It's fine if it only has one element.

Comment: So I have tried to change the ParentClass to:
 
`public class ParentClass
 {
     public Dictionary<string, InnerClass> Currencies { get; set; }
 }`

But still no luck @user2864740

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newtonsoft didn't seem to have any problem with it..

```
    public partial class Blah
    {
        [JsonProperty("currencies")]
        public Dictionary<string, Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Currency
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("symbol")]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
    }
```

And

```
var blah = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Blah[]>(jsonString);
```

[image]

..though it's probably worth noting I think you have your parent and outer the wrong way round if this json is just a fragment..

[image]